# Spring boot 2 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, password

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private static final String USER_SQL = "SELECT" +
            " id," +
            " login," +
            " password" +
            " FROM" +
            " user" +
            " WHERE" +
            " login = ?";

    private static final String ROLE_SQL = "SELECT" +
            " id," +
            " login," +
            " role" +
            " FROM" +
            " user" +
            " WHERE" +
            " login = ?";

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/loginUp").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signUp").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/loginUp")
                .loginPage("/loginUp")
                .failureUrl("/loginUp")
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(USER_SQL)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(ROLE_SQL)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь настроить конфиг но при попытке авторизации мне возвращает ошибку с зашифрованным паролем:

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$2a$10$ZG2UwNC.PNKoQyWLEAPj6eALixruO9nNinM0Mxi2RdwvMpcxSSCDy"

Я думаю что ошибка в присвоении/проверки ролей, потому что я не понимаю как оно может определять роли и давать доступ, в том виде что реализовано у меня

Comment: Попробуйте изменить запрос `USER_SQL` для метода `usersByUsernameQuery`  [согласно документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.html#usersByUsernameQuery-java.lang.String-),  пример `select username,password,enabled from users where username = ?` в нем не должно быть никаких id. Аналогично для запроса `ROLE_SQL` и метода `authoritiesByUsernameQuery`.

Comment: я уже и так и сяк поигрался с запросом, убирал, вставлял он либо мне в ошибке роль возвращает либо пароль

Comment: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT login, password FROM user WHERE login = ?]; Column Index out of range, 3 > 2. ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 3 > 2. если я оставляю только login и password то мне благополучно возвращается это

Comment: Запрос должен возвращать 3 параметра, попробуйте `SELECT login, password, true FROM user WHERE login = ?`, или если есть поле `enabled ` то укажите его.

Comment: спасибо, заработало, только один вопрос а почему true, 3 параметр за что отвечает?

Comment: смотрите `UserDetails.isEnabled`: [Указывает, включен или отключен пользователь. Отключенный пользователь не может быть аутентифицирован.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html#isEnabled())